# Issue with step in the code. Require assistance

Tags: matlab, plot

Good evening,
I have a code working just fine as follows:

```
r=1.6;
M=0.000207;
D=-0.0256;
kappa=0.5;
gamma=20;%\W\km
Pp=0.2;
L=462.5;
SQ=sqrt(-(0.5*D)^2 +M);
z=0:0.1:L;
A=kappa*SQ.*(z-L);
B=((sqrt(M)/r)+(D/2))/(SQ);
C=EA(B);
E=SQ*cot(A+C);
Pminus=E-(D/2);
Pplus=M./Pminus;
P0=Pplus+Pminus+D;
CST1=Pplus.*Pminus;
CST2=P0-Pplus-Pminus;
dP0dz=kappa.*P0.*(Pplus-Pminus);
figure
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
plot(z,Pplus*1000, 'b',z,Pminus*1000,'r',z,P0*1000,'k','Linewidth',4);
xlabel('z(m)')
ylabel('Power (mW)')
legend('P_+','P_-','P_0','D','M','r','Orientation','horizontal')
%str = sprintf('D = %.4f , M = %.9f, and r =%.3f ',D,M,r);
%title(str);
xlim([0 L])
N=gamma.*Pp;%gamma Pp with units \km
y1=0.5*kappa.*1000*(Pplus+Pminus);
y2 =y1./N;
figure
hax=axes;
[ax,p1,p2] = plotyy(z,y1,z,y2,'plot','plot');
 set(ax,{'ycolor'},{'k';'k'}) 
set(ax,{'fontsize'},{18;18})
 set(p1,'linewidth',4)% to change the first line
 set(p2,'linewidth',4) % to change the second line
 set(p1,'Color','b')% to change the first line
 set(p2,'Color','b') % to change the second line
%str = sprintf('D = %.6f  ',D);
%title(str);
ylabel(ax(1),'K_{SBS}(km^{-1})','fontsize',18,...
 'Color','k') % label left y-axis
ylabel(ax(2),'K_{SBS}( \gamma P )','fontsize',18,...
'Color','k') % label right y-axis
xlabel(ax(2),'z(m)','fontsize',18,...
'Color','k')% label x-axis
set(ax(1),'XLim',[0 L])
set(ax(2),'XLim',[0 L])
set(ax(1),'YLim',[min(y1) max(y1)])
set(ax(2),'YLim',[min(y2) max(y2)])
zz1=(max(y1)-min(y1))./4;
zz2=(max(y2)-min(y2))./4;
set(ax(1),'YTick',min(y1):zz1: max(y1) )
set(ax(2),'YTick',min(y2):zz2: max(y2) )
legend('K_{SBS}(km^{-1})')
% figure
% set(gca,'fontsize',18)
% plot(z,1000*dP0dz,'Linewidth',4);
% xlabel('z(m)')
% ylabel('dP_0/dz')
% xlim([0 L])
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
N=gamma.*Pp;%\km
lamdazero=1550;
lamdapump=linspace(1535,1560,100000);
lamdasignal=1545;
beta3=0.06;
beta4=-1*10^-4;
c=2*pi*299792458/1000;

A0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdazero);
B0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdasignal);

Third0=beta3.*(c.^3).*A0.*(B0.^2);
Fourth0=beta4.*(1./2).*c.^4.*(A0.^2).*(B0.^2);

Fourorder=c.^4.*beta4.*(1/12).*(B0).^4;
deltabeta=Third0+Fourth0+Fourorder;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%NO SBS
total0=deltabeta+(2.*N);
g0=((sqrt((N.^2)-(total0./2).^2)));
Gain0=((((N./(g0)).^2).*(sinh(g0.*L/1000)).^2));
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
g0=1.1*10^-11;
Aeff=1.1*10^-11;
PSBS=0.016;
SBS=(g0.*PSBS.*1000)./Aeff; 
totalsbs=deltabeta+(2.*N)-SBS/2;
gsbs=((sqrt((N.^2)-(totalsbs./2).^2)));
Gainsbs=((((N./(gsbs)).^2).*(sinh(gsbs.*L/1000)).^2));
n=35;
first=round(1*(L/n));
step=round(L/n);
last=L;
 for jj=1:length(deltabeta)
 M = eye(2);
 for ii = first:step:last;
 tsv=deltabeta(jj)+(2*N)-(y1(z==(ii-round(0.5*(L/n)))));
 gsv=((sqrt((N.^2)-(tsv./2).^2)));
 F1=1i*tsv;
 F2=2*gsv;
 F3=F1./F2;
 F4=1i*(N./gsv);
 M1=cosh(gsv.*(step/1000))+(F3.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000)));
 M2=F4.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000));
 M3=-F4.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000));
 M4=cosh(gsv.*(step/1000))-(F3.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000)));
 M=M*[M1 M2;M3 M4];
 TeRm=P0(z==ii)/P0(z==(ii-step));
 M=[sqrt(TeRm) 0;0 1]*M;
 end
 Gv(1,jj)=M(1,1).*conj(M(1,1));
 end
FigHandle = figure;
figureh=plot(lamdapump,10*log10(1+Gain0),'b',lamdapump,10*log10(1+Gainsbs),'g',lamdapump,10*log10(Gv),'r','Linewidth',5);
hold on
xlabel('\lambda_P (nm)','Fontsize',18)
ylabel('Signal Gain (dB)','Fontsize',18)
legend('Without SBS',' With SBS ideal ',' With SBS actual')
% title('Gain curves with SBS','fontsize',18)
set(gca,'XTick',1536:3:1560)
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
ylim([0 12])
hold off
```

My issue is that when changing the parameter L into a value smaller than one like with some changes in the parameters:

```
    r=1.8;
M=0.80322;
D=-1.69;
kappa=700/4.6;
gamma=5285;%\W\km
Pp=7.6;
L=0.045333;
SQ=sqrt(-(0.5*D)^2 +M);
z=0:0.00001:L;
A=kappa*SQ.*(z-L);
B=((sqrt(M)/r)+(D/2))/(SQ);
C=EA(B);
E=SQ*cot(A+C);
Pminus=E-(D/2);
Pplus=M./Pminus;
P0=Pplus+Pminus+D;
CST1=Pplus.*Pminus;
CST2=P0-Pplus-Pminus;
dP0dz=kappa.*P0.*(Pplus-Pminus);
figure
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
plot(z,Pplus*1000, 'b',z,Pminus*1000,'r',z,P0*1000,'k','Linewidth',4);
xlabel('z(m)')
ylabel('Power (mW)')
legend('P_+','P_-','P_0','D','M','r','Orientation','horizontal')
%str = sprintf('D = %.4f , M = %.9f, and r =%.3f ',D,M,r);
%title(str);
xlim([0 L])
N=gamma.*Pp;%gamma Pp with units \km
y1=0.5*kappa.*1000*(Pplus+Pminus);
y2 =y1./N;
figure
hax=axes;
[ax,p1,p2] = plotyy(z,y1,z,y2,'plot','plot');
 set(ax,{'ycolor'},{'k';'k'}) 
set(ax,{'fontsize'},{18;18})
 set(p1,'linewidth',4)% to change the first line
 set(p2,'linewidth',4) % to change the second line
 set(p1,'Color','b')% to change the first line
 set(p2,'Color','b') % to change the second line
%str = sprintf('D = %.6f  ',D);
%title(str);
ylabel(ax(1),'K_{SBS}(km^{-1})','fontsize',18,...
 'Color','k') % label left y-axis
ylabel(ax(2),'K_{SBS}( \gamma P )','fontsize',18,...
'Color','k') % label right y-axis
xlabel(ax(2),'z(m)','fontsize',18,...
'Color','k')% label x-axis
set(ax(1),'XLim',[0 L])
set(ax(2),'XLim',[0 L])
set(ax(1),'YLim',[min(y1) max(y1)])
set(ax(2),'YLim',[min(y2) max(y2)])
zz1=(max(y1)-min(y1))./4;
zz2=(max(y2)-min(y2))./4;
set(ax(1),'YTick',min(y1):zz1: max(y1) )
set(ax(2),'YTick',min(y2):zz2: max(y2) )
legend('K_{SBS}(km^{-1})')
% figure
% set(gca,'fontsize',18)
% plot(z,1000*dP0dz,'Linewidth',4);
% xlabel('z(m)')
% ylabel('dP_0/dz')
% xlim([0 L])
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
N=gamma.*Pp;%\km
lamdazero=1556;
lamdapump=linspace(1300,1800,100000);
lamdasignal=1536;
beta3=1.26;
beta4=0;
c=2*pi*299792458/1000;

A0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdazero);
B0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdasignal);

Third0=beta3.*(c.^3).*A0.*(B0.^2);
Fourth0=beta4.*(1./2).*c.^4.*(A0.^2).*(B0.^2);

Fourorder=c.^4.*beta4.*(1/12).*(B0).^4;
deltabeta=Third0+Fourth0+Fourorder;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%NO SBS
total0=deltabeta+(2.*N);
g0=((sqrt((N.^2)-(total0./2).^2)));
Gain0=((((N./(g0)).^2).*(sinh(g0.*L/1000)).^2));
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
g0=0.7*10^-9;
Aeff=2.3*10^-12;
PSBS=Pp*4/57.5;
SBS=(g0.*PSBS.*1000)./Aeff; 
totalsbs=deltabeta+(2.*N)-SBS/2;
gsbs=((sqrt((N.^2)-(totalsbs./2).^2)));
Gainsbs=((((N./(gsbs)).^2).*(sinh(gsbs.*L/1000)).^2));

n=35;
first=(1*(L/n));
step=(L/n);
last=L;
 for jj=1:length(deltabeta)
 M = eye(2);
 for ii = first:step:last;
 tsv=deltabeta(jj)+(2*N)-(y1(z==(ii-(0.5*(L/n)))));
 gsv=((sqrt((N.^2)-(tsv./2).^2)));
 F1=1i*tsv;
 F2=2*gsv;
 F3=F1./F2;
 F4=1i*(N./gsv);
 M1=cosh(gsv.*(step/1000))+(F3.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000)));
 M2=F4.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000));
 M3=-F4.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000));
 M4=cosh(gsv.*(step/1000))-(F3.*sinh(gsv.*(step/1000)));
 M=M*[M1 M2;M3 M4];
 TeRm=P0(z==ii)/P0(z==(ii-step));
 M=[sqrt(TeRm) 0;0 1]*M;
 end
 Gv(1,jj)=M(1,1).*conj(M(1,1));
 end
FigHandle = figure;
figureh=plot(lamdapump,10*log10(1+Gain0),'b',lamdapump,10*log10(1+Gainsbs),'g',lamdapump,10*log10(Gv),'r','Linewidth',5);
hold on
xlabel('\lambda_P (nm)','Fontsize',18)
ylabel('Signal Gain (dB)','Fontsize',18)
legend('Without SBS',' With SBS ideal ',' With SBS actual')
title('Gain curves with SBS','fontsize',18)
%set(gca,'XTick',1300:10:1800)
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
%ylim([0 12])
hold off
```

The code does not work. The reason in my opinion is that when using the function round it rounds to zero. If i remove the round function it no longer works. Any thoughts on how can I make my code work again?
Is there any chance to work around round function because i need to take n steps. However I simply can not do so because L is very small. I need the value of L to stay small.
My apologizes for the long codes and explanations. Be free to ask ![image: ![The image shows the outcome of the first code which is working just fine.In the second code, the third figure which is the main figure is not plotting and the error as expected is vectors must have same length]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCw0S.png)

Comment: I am not able to run your code, which makes it very difficult to help you without a concrete problem. Please provide (1) a minimal working example and (2) define very concretely what you mean by not working (error message, wrong results, ...)

Comment: Good morning I have to apologize because of the missing function EA:
function  y  = EA(x)

 y = acot(x);

y(y<0)=y(y<0)+pi;

return

Comment: As for why it is not working I have a feeling that because the parameter L is now much smaller and I want to take certain steps, it will simply give take zero steps and thus no work is done.

Comment: That is definitely the case if you use `round`, but you removed it in your second code.

Comment: Well I had to remove round in the second case. Otherwise it would round my steps to zero and then the error shows up:
Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent. 

 I do not know what it means and I am not sure what more can I do :(